# focusing a richtextbox which has keyPressEventListener control to a method and extends Metroframeworks form?

Tags: c#, richtextbox

[This is the UI of the Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM5ns.png)

```
    public partial class Form1 : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

       this.Controls.Add(richTextBox1);
        richTextBox1.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(richTextBox1_KeyPress);
        richTextBox1.Select();
        //richTextBox1.BringToFront();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = loadText("coding.txt");
        //this.ActiveControl = richTextBox1;
        richTextBox1.Select();


    }
private void richTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
       // e.Handled = false;
        //richTextBox1.Focus();

        char key = e.KeyChar;
        char[] c = richTextBox1.Text.ToCharArray();
        next++;
        if (next == 0)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }


        //here we check number and chars and considering this colour char and button
        for (int i = 0; i < this.panel1.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            if (this.panel1.Controls[i].Name.Substring(0, 4).ToLower().CompareTo("btn" + key.ToString().ToLower()) == 0 && this.panel1.Controls[i].Name.Length <= 4)
                textAndButtonColour((Button)this.panel1.Controls[i], c, next, key);

        }

        //for checking  symbols                                                                                     

        if ((int)key == 33) textAndButtonColour(btn1, c, next, key);
        if ((int)key == 64) textAndButtonColour(btn2, c, next, key);
        if ((int)key == 35) textAndButtonColour(btn3, c, next, key);
        if ((int)key == 36) textAndButtonColour(btn4, c, next, key);
        if ((int)key == 37) textAndButtonColour(btn5, c, next, key);
        if ((int)key == 94) textAndButtonColour(btn6, c, next, key);
        if ((int)key == 38) textAndButtonColour(btn7, c, next, key);
        if ((int)key == 42) textAndButtonColour(btn8, c, next, key);
        if ((int)key == 40) textAndButtonColour(btn9, c, next, key);
        if ((int)key == 41) textAndButtonColour(btn0, c, next, key);




        if ((int)key == 123 || (int)key == 91) textAndButtonColour(btnopenbrace, c, next, key);
        if ((int)key == 125 || (int)key == 93) textAndButtonColour(btnclosebrace, c, next, key);
        if ((int)key == 58 || (int)key == 59) textAndButtonColour(btnsemi, c, next, key);
        if ((int)key == 34 || (int)key == 39) textAndButtonColour(btndouble, c, next, key);
        if ((int)key == 60 || (int)key == 44) textAndButtonColour(btncomma, c, next, key);
        if ((int)key == 62 || (int)key == 46) textAndButtonColour(btndot, c, next, key);
        if ((int)key == 63 || (int)key == 47) textAndButtonColour(btnbackslash, c, next, key);
        if ((int)key == 124 || (int)key == 92) textAndButtonColour(btnforwardslash, c, next, key);
        if ((int)key == 95 || (int)key == 45) textAndButtonColour(btnminus, c, next, key);
        if ((int)key == 43 || (int)key == 61) textAndButtonColour(btnequals, c, next, key);

        //check spacebar and enter keys
        if ((int)key == 32) textAndButtonColour(btnspacebar, c, next, key);
        if ((int)key == 13) textAndButtonColour(btnenter, c, next, key);

        //e.Handled = true;

        if (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            next--;
        }

        //stop timer when the number of keypesses equal to the number of letters displayed in the box
        if (c.Length == next + 1)
        {

            timer1.Stop();

            //richTextBox1.Text = loadText(fileName);
            //richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
            //richTextBox1.SelectionLength = next;
            //richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
            //richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;

            //charCorrect.Text = correct.ToString();
            //charIncorrect.Text = incorrect.ToString();
        }





        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

For your i am not extending form class instead i am using Metroframework form.
I need to focus richtextbox when form loads. I ensured tabindex is ok, i used focus method - not working, select method is working but then keypresseventlistener contorl is not working

Comment: @Hans Passant If I use Select() in constructor I am not geting my keyPress events . Then richtextbox focuses but i am not getting key press events

Comment: May be the cursor/focus is there, but you can not see it because of scrolled up?

Comment: no i have to click on the richTextBox to contorl to focus  @Shaharyar

Comment: Where do you use `Select()`? Can you please share the updated code?

Comment: kindly see the code Shaharyar i updated it

Comment: Remove `Focus()` from constructor, then try. `Focus()` can not be used in constructor because component is not in the visible state yet, and put your `Select()` just after the event subscribing line in constructor.